# Layout a knob and button view

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I want to have this complex control ported into my Android XML Layout:

I need the buttons (heart, cloud,...) and the central knob as ImageButtons, so they should be separate objects and positioned in exact positions.

The problem is how to layout such complex button and backgrounds so it displays correctly on multiple devices having different resolutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you are allowed to implement it dynamically here are some hints:

1. **Create separate images**(backgrounds)

   - 1 image for the knob
   - 1 image for each small button
   - 1 image for the background
2. **Radius**

   - measure the distance from the center of the background to the point where a small button should be placed (the radius of the background pattern) in pixels.
   - you might need different sizes for different screens (different resolutions)
3. **Place the buttons**:

   - place the background image and the knob [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) so that the center of the knob matches the center of the background - both images should be rectangular, so the central point should be at the crossing point of the diagonals
   - use [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates) to [retrieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates#Cartesian_coordinates) the cartesian (x,y) coordinates of the small buttons - their centers should lie on those points
4. **Hit test**

   - all your images should have transparent background
   - you can implement the hit test to be successful only when the event is in the non-transparent part of the ImageButton background
5. **Rotation**

   - To rotate the knob you can look for more info about rotating an ImageButton's background. I haven't tried something like this...

Comment: I have a problem in placing buttons: their size is not same as their pixel size, they are much bigger!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to intercept onTouchEvent() and process the raw events. This way you would know where on your picture the user's finger is.

A simpler solution would be to use a RelativeLayout, if you can tolerate square buttons beneath the round icons. (3 states, normal-selected-pressed.) In fact, you don't need buttons, you may just make your views clickable.

I'm not sure what you want the user to do with the central knob: press it, turn with two or three fingers, etc. In principle, you may have a square view whose corners are covered by non-clickable transparent square views (or should they be clickable instead? the idea is that the clicks in that area should not be received by the knob).

One more possible approach is not to implement separate buttons, but to have one square image for each state of the whole combination of controls.

You will definitely have to know the actual size of your image -- see `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` and `getMeasuredWidth()`/`getMeasuredHeight()` (when a click happens, the latter two already may be used, although before the layout happens they return zero).

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu) or [CircleLayout](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout) and customize it to support a widget positioned in the centre. Or you can create your own layout from scratch. Good article how to do so is available [here](http://arpitonline.com/blog/2012/07/01/creating-custom-layouts-for-android/).